# can we Capture onchange Event for Dynamic TextAreas Without Defining Class in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a requirement where I need to capture the onchange event of a textarea. The challenge is that the textarea is dynamic, and its number can vary based on user input (e.g., single or multiple textareas).

Here is an example of how the HTML looks:

```
<textarea name="userInput1" id="userInput1" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput2" id="userInput2" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput3" id="userInput3" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<!-- ... -->
<textarea name="userInputN" id="userInputN" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
```

And the jQuery code I'm using to capture the onchange event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".textareaClass").on("change", function() {
        var textareaValue = $(this).val();
        // My logic
    });
});
```

**My question is: Can I use the class attribute "textareaClass" without defining the class in the CSS? Is this considered standard practice, or is there a better way to capture the onchange event for dynamically generated textareas?**

I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: `$('textarea').on("change", function() {`

Comment: you can directly go for `$('textarea').on("change", function() {` no need of id or class checking:https://jsfiddle.net/g0xsf8b7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have *id*, you can use id starts with [attribute_selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4) like the following way:

```
('textarea[id^=userInput]').on("change", function() {...
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea[id^=userInput]').on("change", function() {
    var textareaValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="userInput1" id="userInput1" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput2" id="userInput2" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput3" id="userInput3" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<!-- ... -->
<textarea name="userInputN" id="userInputN" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. 

 I have used something like

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea[id*=userInput]').on("change", function() {
    var textareaValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(this.value);
  });
}); as my actual ID's are "userForm.userInput1 ,"userForm.userInput2" and "userForm.userInput3" ............."userForm.userInputN"

Comment: @unknown, in that case you are using attribute contains selector and will work also in your case:)

Comment: @unknown you can directly go for `$('textarea').on("change", function() {` no need of id or class checking:https://jsfiddle.net/g0xsf8b7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('[id^=userInput]')` which means using id which starts with string `userInput`, as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=userInput]').on("change", function() {
        var textareaValue = $(this).val();
        console.log("value", textareaValue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<textarea name="userInput1" id="userInput1" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput2" id="userInput2" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<textarea name="userInput3" id="userInput3" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
<!-- ... -->
<textarea name="userInputN" id="userInputN" rows="4" cols="50" class="textareaClass"></textarea>
And the jQuery code I'm using to capture the onchange event:
```

Comment: @unknown you can directly go for `$('textarea').on("change", function() {` no need of id or class checking:https://jsfiddle.net/g0xsf8b7/